# ckeditor.replace not working when page is loaded but works fine when executed from console

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in a web application, when I added the ckeditor.replace code in the html template I get an error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getEditor' of undefined ". On the same page if I endter CKEDITOR.replace('id_taskDetails'); in the console I see all the buttons.

BTW, I get the alert.

I tried the solution from here: [Inline CKEditor with toolbar on generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379003/inline-ckeditor-with-toolbar-on-generated-code)

This stops the error but still no toolbar.

What am I missing?

```
<script>
    alert('foo');
    CKEDITOR.replace('id_taskDetails');
</script>
<div id="content">
<form action="/createTask/Test1/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="basic-grey">
<p><label for="id_taskName">Task Name:</label> <input id="id_taskName" maxlength="64"       name="taskName" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="id_taskDetails">Details:</label> <textarea cols="60" id="id_taskDetails"  name="taskDetails" rows="40">
</textarea></p>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="save" value="Next">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to post a question on StackOverflow before I get it right.

I used the jquery load function to make sure the page completely loaded before calling the ckeditor replace call and it works fine now.

```
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
CKEDITOR.replace('id_taskDetails');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`CKEDITOR.replace` must be executed when the element which you try to replace exists, so **after** it.

```
<p><label for="id_taskDetails">Details:</label> <textarea cols="60" id="id_taskDetails"  name="taskDetails" rows="40">
</textarea></p>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('id_taskDetails');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the note, yes I had tried that too but it did not work. I am working with Django and using the inbuilt form.as_p method to render the page which might be causing the issue.